# Using MIP fitting on toilet supply pipe

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I am needing to replace an angle stop for a residential toilet, an older-style multi-turn that won't shut the supply off anymore. I was thinking of replacing it with a quarter-turn valve, either compression or soldered.

However, it occurred to me that I might be able to sweat a 1/2" MIP adapter onto the copper line and then use an angle stop that threads into that. My thinking is that this would make it easier to replace future angle stops because I won't have to deal with pulling off a compression fitting or taking out a torch.

Is this something that can be done, or are there reasons not to do it?

Thank you.

Edit: I should add that I am located in Ontario, Canada, in case there are code issues.

Comment: Sounds like you're fairly experienced, but perhaps consider just rebuilding the multi turn stop in place by replacing the shaft and washers/bushings.